# Cannot play HTML5 video in Cordova app on iOS if the video src changes

Tags: javascript, ios, html, cordova

I am working on a Cordova based app for iOS. I have programmatically added a `<video>` element to the page and it plays fine. However, if I change the video player's source then I am unable to make the video play again. Using the same code in an Electron app works just fine to swap out video clips on the fly. What can I do to make video source swapping work on iOS?

Comment: Does the same code work within iOS safari? Could you provide examples of the code you are using for the video element and to change the source.

Comment: I'll try to get a minimal example setup shortly.

Comment: Starting with a blank Cordova project I seem to be able to change the source without issue, so there must be something funky going on in my project...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out my issue was that I was changing the source of my captions as well. I was storing a reference to my text track element as a field of my video player element for convenience which worked fine in Electron. For Cordova I guess that stored reference was invalid and caused my function to exit early, thus skipping the part where I called `play()`. Looking up the text track fresh at time of swapping sources solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I vaguely remember in the past that one had to call `.load()` on the `video` element in order to reset everything. I am not sure if this is still the case though.

Comment: I found one SO question that implied that might help me, but unfortunately adding a `video.load()` after changing the source did not seem to help me.